# Inconsistent superscript placement in $q_x^{n_x} q_y^{n_y}$

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment, superscripts

As part of a document, I am typesetting the objects `q_x^{n_x}` and `q_y^{n_y}` right next to each other, as

```
\frac{ q_x^{n_x} q_y^{n_y} }{2}
```

[image]

It bugs me that the `n_y` gets displayed at a different baseline than the `n_x`, though I understand the core reason for it (i.e. probably due to the taller subscript in `q_y`).

Is there a way to enforce consistency in the typesetting of this combination?

Comment: @campa No, that's probably enough. I'd be interested to know why it works, but I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aligning subscripts and superscripts requires some thought and examination of the relative shapes: the combinations are really too many for being able to devise an automatic solution.

In your case there are no descenders in the subscripts to the first “q”, but there are two in the second case. However the subscript “y” in the superscript doesn't really need space below it, because it sticks clear of the main subscript. So this case calls for “smashing the descender”:

In the following example, the first line is *au naturel*, the second line implements Mico's excellent suggestion, the third one improves on it. In the fourth line the two solutions are side-by-side for better comparing them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vy}{\vphantom{y}} % vertical phantom with height and depth of "y" glyph
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\frac{ q_x^{n_x} q_y^{n_y} }{2} \\
\frac{ q_{x\vy}^{n_{x\vy}} q_y^{n_y} }{2} \\
\frac{ q_{x\vy}^{n_{x}} q_y^{n_{\smash[b]{y}}} }{2} \\[\medskipamount]
\frac{ q_{x\vy}^{n_{x\vy}} q_y^{n_y} }{2}
\frac{ q_{x\vy}^{n_{x}} q_y^{n_{\smash[b]{y}}} }{2}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm blushing... :-)

Comment: @Mico Been there, done that! `;-)`

Comment: Can you comment on the relationship between these solutions and the `\displaystyle` solution proposed in the comments?

Comment: @E.P. I don't consider `\displaystyle` a solution; it's just by chance that, in this case, it gives the same result as with the “double `\vphantom`” trick.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a "vertical phantom" -- specifically, an invisible object that has the height and depth of the glyph "y" -- to adjust the positions of the two "x" characters in the first subformula, *viz.*, `q_x^{n_x}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\vy}{\vphantom{y}} % vertical phantom with height and depth of "y" glyph
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\frac{ q_x^{n_x} q_y^{n_y} }{2} 
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
\frac{ q_{x\vy}^{n_{x\vy}} q_y^{n_y} }{2}
$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: While the `\vphantom` method succeeds in placing all sub- and superscripts at mutually consistent heights, one might object that the `x` and `y` subscripts to `q` are positioned "too high". To force these subscripts to be placed a bit lower, then, one can insert `\mathstrut` directives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\vy}{\vphantom{y}} % vertical phantom
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\frac{ q_x^{n_x} q_y^{n_y} }{2} 
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
\frac{ q_{x\mathstrut}^{n_{x\vy}} q_{y\mathstrut}^{n_{y}} }{2}
$
\end{document}
```